# Ag-grid filter does not recognize values in the main key

Tags: angular5, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We use aggrid 15.0.0 with Angular5 (we also have the enterprise license) and I need to use tree data.
I use the example from here (the Organisational Hierarchy example)
https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/15.0.0/javascript-grid-tree-data/#gsc.tab=0
And unfortunately I am not able to see it running in Plunkr, seems like this demo is broken.
My issue is that when I filter by a value that is in the main column no results are returned, this only works for the children values.

> This does not work:

[image: Does not work]

> This works:
>   [image: This works:]

Comment: could you create own sample for that and provide a plnkr

Comment: This: https://plnkr.co/edit/bMpdmKj2atOGOMBLNQwl?p=preview
Should be a working example from the Ag-grid website but it doesn't even load

Comment: you are using a quick filter?

Comment: @un.spike yes. Anyway, I upgraded to version 19 and it works